# What is the name of the iOS browser app that automatically navigates to the URL that is on the clipboard upon launch?

Tags: ios, applications, web-browser

There is an iOS browser app that will *automatically navigate to a URL upon app launch if there is a URL on the clipboard* but I cannot remember the app. Does anyone know?

Comment: This must be a jailbreak application, no?

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Why do you say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mercury](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mercury-web-browser/id331012646?mt=8) (free, or $0.99 [pro version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mercury-browser-pro-best-web/id348701575?mt=8)) will prompt you to open a copied URL on launch. You tap "Okay" and it opens a new tab in the foreground containing the page.

[image]

I haven't been able to find an iOS browser which automatically opens the URL on the clipboard with no user action.

Comment: I think this app has been taken off the App Store